# Excel VBA - Variable declared as integer not saving integer value (Runtime error 1004)

Tags: excel, vba, variables, integer, save

I've been trying to debug for hours getting Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. I've located what causes the error I think, can't figure out reason.

I'm processing two sheets with same code.
bSheet1 = True  'if code is run from sheet1)
bSheet2 = True  'if code is run from sheet2)

both Boolean variables are given initial value of False.

If bSheet1 = True then iRowYear = iRowYear_Sheet1  'assigned value earlier in code, irowYear_Sheet1 =4
if bSheet2 = True then iRowYear = c1.Row-2

iRowYear is declared as an integer like regular variable. It will be the same row# for Sheet1. I have declared iRowYear_Sheet1 as an integer and assigned it value of 4 ("iRowYear_Sheet1=4) earlier in code.
"c1" is cell range, declared as range. code uses it to loop through each cell from first project name to last.
Year is always two rows above project name in Sheet2.

The calculations and Boolean values all show correctly when debugging...row number shows correctly when I hover over "c1.Row-1" but iRowYear keeps on showing "0". Although the "If" statement holds true and code is read when stepping through.

The code works fine when processing Sheet1, but for sheet two, the calculated value "c1.Row-1" simply doesn't get saved in iRowYear variable, and error is thrown later in the code.

There are times, usually the first run or so when it actually processes data for Sheet2, but randomly gets stuck, and once stuck it continues to throw error, each time indicating iRowYear is "0".

----------Additional info------------
There's a lot of code with various Calls so can't paste everything...I'm also simplifying variable names here. Here's where the immediate loop starts. Code goes on to close the loops and ends If statements...and it runs fine for sheet1. It's for Sheet2 where there is error on the last statement below. Randomly the error sometimes occurs later in the code for same variable (iRowYear) showing as zero:

Option Explicit

Global c1 as range
Global iRowYear As Integer
Global Const iRowYear_Sheet1 = 4  'Row# same for sheet1, varies for sheet2

.....
'There are loops and conditions before this...only pasting start of immediate loop...loops and conditions working ok

For Each c1 In wsSchedule.Range(Cells(iRowFirst, iCol_Status), Cells(iRowLast, iCol_Status))

If c1.Value2 = "GO" Then

```
    If bSheet1 = True Then iRowYear = iRowYear_Sheet1    
    If bSheet2 = True Then iRowYear = (c1.Row - 2)    

    iColLast = wsSchedule.Cells(iRowYear, 130).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

'etc...

Error on last line showing iRowYear as zero, even though "c1.Row-2" showing correct integer value with mouseover. bSheet1 is showing false and bSheet2 is showing True with mouseover. Code steps through correctly but iRowYear is not storing the output of "c1.Row-2"...it remains zero.

Comment: Seeing more code would probably help here. Cannot see how (if) you qualified your ranges, among other things ~

Comment: You need to post your actual code.

Comment: You stated *'irow_Sheet1 available as constant'* then wondered*'c1.Row-1" simply doesn't get saved in iRowYear variable'*. Well, which is it? Is iRowYear  a constant or a variable? You cannot reassign a public constant.

Comment: Sorry, didn't paste code because it's a lot of code with three calls before this point...and I've simplified the variables names for here. Here's where the range is declared:

Comment: I've added some additional info and For statement for the range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by modifying "If" statement.
In my actual code I was assigning value to two variables in If statement:

```
If bSheet2 = True Then iRowYear = (c1.Row-2) AND (iRowMonth=c1.Row-1)
```

I stupidly omitted iRowMonth in my question to save time. 
Code seems to be running fine after I changed the If statement to:

```
If bSheet2 = True Then  
    iRowYear = c1.Row-2  
    iRowMonth = c1.Row-1  
End If
```

Still a little baffled since there were times the code still ran okay for Sheet1.

Thanks to all for input, and I apologize for the incomplete question.